# Python: How to set default value for a attribute in child class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, attributes, parent-child

I am working on Python and I have defined a Parent class as follows

```
class Country:
    """Models countries"""
    def __init__(self, name, population, continent, zone):
        """Initiates the Country class"""
        self.na = name
        self.co = continent
        self.zo = zone
        self.po = population
```

I have also defined two method in this class.
I have created a subclass named Europe_country in which I want to set default value of continent and zone to 'Europe' and 'Temperate' respectively.

I have tried to do it like this

```
class Europe_country(Country):
    """Models European countries specifically"""
    co = 'Europe'
    zo = 'Temperate'

europe_1 = Europe_country('Abc', 999)
```

But obviously I am wrong. I am unable to find a solution for this problem on the internet. Please help.

Comment: [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this:

```
class Country:
    """Models countries"""
    def __init__(self, name, population, continent, zone):
        """Initiates the Country class"""
        self.na = name
        self.co = continent
        self.zo = zone
        self.po = population
        
class Europe_country(Country):
    """Models European countries specifically"""
    def __init__(self, name, population):
        super().__init__(name, population, "Europe", "Temperate")

europe_1 = Europe_country('Abc', 999)
```

Call the parent constructor with predefined values and set the rest from the child constructor.

Answer (score 2):

your subclass only accepts 2 inputs, so you need to overwrite the `__init__` of the parent class to accept only 2 inputs, you can then invoke the **init** of the parent class passing your two inputs and your set values.

```py
class Country:
    """Models countries"""

    def __init__(self, name, population, continent, zone):
        """Initiates the Country class"""
        self.na = name
        self.co = continent
        self.zo = zone
        self.po = population

class Europe_country(Country):
    """Models European countries specifically"""
    co = 'Europe'
    zo = 'Temperate'

    def __init__(self, name, population):
        super().__init__(name, population, self.co, self.zo)

europe_1 = Europe_country('Abc', 999)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `super` to force the initalization of the base class while taking 2 other parameters in the child class:

```py
class Europe_country(Country):
    """Models European countries specifically"""
    def __init__(name, population):
        super().__init__(name, population, "Europe", "Temperate")
```