# Python dataclass inheritance with default values

Tags: python, inheritance, python-dataclasses

I am attempting to subclass a Python dataclass, where the subclass will have all the same fields as the parent class, except certain fields will be constrained to specific values.

That is, I am attempting to do something like this:

```
@dataclass
class Polygon:
    perimeter: float
    number_of_sides: int

class Triangle(Polygon):
    perimeter: float
    number_of_sides: int = 3
```

This works until I attempt to actually use the `Triangle` class without specifying `number_of_sides`.

This works as expected:

```
polygon = Polygon(perimeter=5.0, number_of_sides=6)
triangle = Triangle(perimeter=5.0, number_of_sides=3)
```

This does not work:

```
triangle_using_defaults = Triangle(perimeter=5.0)
```

Error message is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dmayo/PycharmProjects/playground/interval/shape.py", line 17, in <module>
    triangle_using_defaults = Triangle(perimeter=5.0)
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Polygon.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'number_of_sides'
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this help: [python-how-to-set-default-value-for-a-attribute-in-child-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64465604/python-how-to-set-default-value-for-a-attribute-in-child-class)

Comment: Note that as an aside it seems like a design problem that you could create a Triangle instance with four sides (`triangle = Triangle(perimeter=5.0, number_of_sides=4`)

Comment: The `dataclass` decorator turns the class attribute `number_of_sides` into special code in the generated methods. The class attribute of the same nam that you add to `Triangle` is unrelated to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `@dataclass` decorator for `Triangle` class;

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Polygon:
    perimeter: float
    number_of_sides: int

@dataclass
class Triangle(Polygon):
    number_of_sides: int = 3

triangle_using_defaults = Triangle(perimeter=5.0)
print(triangle_using_defaults)
```

This will print `Triangle(perimeter=5.0, number_of_sides=3)`

Note: there's no need to specify `perimeter: float` in the subclass, as it is already defined in its parent, unless there is a need to override the parent's definition (as we do with the default value for `number_of_sides`).

Comment: Ah, I see! It seems so clear now. Thank you so much!